# how to show image name from NSArray of UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an array of images, I just want to get the image name from the array
e.g.

```
countryArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"india.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"australia.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"singapore.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"america.png"],
nil] retain];


NSLog(@"image name at row %d is '%@'.",1,[countryArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

It should show `australia.png`, instead it shows:

> image name at row 1 is UIImage: 0x4b14910

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UIImage` doesn't remember its filename once the image is loaded, so there is no direct way to achieve this with a property, e.g. `myImage.name`.

One option is to use a separate `NSMutableArray` to store the names as strings. For instance

```
countryStringArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
@"india",
@"australia",
@"singapore",
@"america",
nil] retain];

countryImageArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:[countryStringArray objectAtIndex:0]],
[UIImage imageNamed:[countryStringArray objectAtIndex:1]],
[UIImage imageNamed:[countryStringArray objectAtIndex:2]],
[UIImage imageNamed:[countryStringArray objectAtIndex:3]],
nil] retain];
```

You could even make use of a `for` loop to populate the `countryImageArray`.

A second option is to use an `NSMutableDictionary`. This is essentially the same thing, in fact you can achieve it by

```
countryDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:countryImageArray forKeys:countryStringArray];
```

but it has some advantages in terms of cleanness of retrieving a specific country image by name. The direct way to define it is

```
[countryDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"india.png"] forKey:@"india"];
[countryDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"australia.png"] forKey:@"australia"];
[countryDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"singapore.png"] forKey:@"singapore"];
[countryDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"america.png"] forKey:@"america"];
```

Comment: @Mohammad: You're most certainly welcome. If this works for you, then you can click the little check mark beside the answer to "accept" it. This way others will know that it helped you, and we'll both earn reputation points for it. Best of luck with your app!